# Check if Browser is Exist in Client Machine

Tags: c#, browser

I'm using C# as a programming platform.

Can anyone help me on how can I populate all existing browser in the client machine.
And I want also to validate first if the browser (firefox.exe) is existing in the client machine before calling the process of

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible under normal circumstances. Imagine all the privacy and security issues if any website you visit can see the programs or files you have on your computer.

Comment: And it does not make sense. If your application is an HTTP server, then it may be accessed by a remote browser on some other machine (unless you restrict the acceptable TCP/IP connections). And your user could use some other browser than firefox....

Comment: @200 - He didn't say anything about this being done from a webpage.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - If I write an application that is a web server and I don't want remote browsers to connect then I would bind the web server to a local only IP address (such as loopback). What does that have to do with his question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to inspect the Uninstall registry keys to determine if specific programs are available. Things to beware of:

1. Different versions of the same browser may populate different uninstall keys (not recommended but it happens)
2. I don't believe internet explorer has a registry key in all situations but if you're running on Windows you should be pretty safe here.

Comment: Not a good idea. You can only check registries if the application is running on Windows IE.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading your comment but I believe you are absolutely correct. You can only access WINDOWS registry on WINDOWS; hence if you are developing on Mono (which I pray no real commercial system ever will) then you are out of luck (sort of). There is always a way and saying otherwise is ridiculous. That said you code to the 90% and tell the rest to conform or use something else.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same situation sometimes ago and the answer what I found after alot of R&D was: It's not possible.